# How to allow users to run jupyter notebooks stored in my database on my server?

Tags: python, django, jupyter-notebook

I have a problem and I need a hint how to approach the problem.

I have django application, in which I have sme jupyter notebooks stored in my database. At this point, users can download notebooks and run them on their compuers.

I would like to add functionality, where user could run notebook online. I was thinking of two solutions:

- first one is to use some free to use online service, like google colab, but I haven't found any with api where I could send file from my database (maybe you know about some?),
- second is to run jupyter hub on my server. I saw how to run jupyter hub remotely, but I don't know how to grant users the access, so they can run notebooks simultaneously, and they don't have access to server itself thorugh it, and do all of this in django.

Do you have any hints that could help me get this functionality?

Comment: To run your notebook in colab, you will have to either store it in GitHub or Google Drive.

Answer (score 1):

JupyterHub is a good approach if you trust your users. However, if you want to run untrusted code (like Google Colab does), you need sandboxing. In that case, you can use a Docker image to run notebooks. For example, [mikebirdgeneau/jupyterlab](https://hub.docker.com/r/mikebirdgeneau/jupyterlab). And there is a docker-compose file example: https://github.com/mikebirdgeneau/jupyterlab-docker/blob/master/docker-compose.yml

Comment: Thanks, I can try, but I'm not very experienced with docker, so I have one quick question that will help me to sart - should it be one image, and on it I could run all notebooks, or for each notebook I would have to first run new image?

Comment: A new container for every user. In other words, a separate sandbox for every user. Otherwise, one user can get control over all other environments (steal and corrupt data, for example).